# Store custom data on a fb-logged user

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I use Parse.com as backend for my application, I have seen that they offer a strong facebook-login support and I would like to implement this feature in my app. Looking through the Docs I can't answer the following:
How can I store my custom data in a facebook logged user? Following the Parse tutorial I came out with:

```
    List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");

    ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions, this, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            if (user == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else
                linkFbUser(user);
        }
    });
```

but I'm not really sure.
I think I should create a new `ParseUser` (if so, what username and password should I use?) and then link this user with the just logged fb-user.
Is it correct? How can I implement this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ParseFacebookUtils.logIn returns you a parse user. A parse user is just an extension of a parseObject. So just like a parseObject, you can add data into the columns in your user table.

In the Parse Data Browser, you can add customised columns to the user table, just like you can any other table in the data browser by just using the +Col button.

So once you have retreived your parseuser from the ParseFacebookUtils.logIn method you can just add data to it and then save the user again to update it e.g.

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions, this, new LogInCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
        if (user == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else
            user.put("exampleColumn", "ColumnValue");
            user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if(null == e){
                        // Saved successfully
                    }
                }
            });
    }
});
```

If you only want to add data to the user when it is a new user you can use the isNew method. i.e

```
if(user.isNew()){
     // Add data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Parse Web UI to add a new table derived from User. There you can add your custom columns then.

Comment: I would like to keep all the user in the same table `User`. Is it possible? Reading the Docs it seems simple, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Parse offers you a schemaless data storage, so there is no problem of storing Users with different property fields. And yes you can keep all Users in the same table.